# How can I use counter-increment to show page numbers on a printed web page?

Tags: html, css, printing

I have the following CSS:

```
@media print {
    div.question-list-footer
    {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        padding-left: 180px;
    }
    div.question-list-footer-center 
    {
        text-align: center;
    }
    @page { counter-reset: page 1}
}

#pageNumber:after { content: counter(page); }
#pageNumber { counter-increment: page; }
```

and the following html on my page:

```
<div class="question-list-footer">
    <div class="question-list-footer-center">
        <span>Page Number: <span id="pageNumber"></span></span><br/>
        Date: @firstItem.Date.Value.ToShortDateString()
        Id: @firstItem.Id
    </div>
</div>
```

and this works when printing except that all pages have "Page Number 1". (IE9, Chrome & FF)  I have been staring at this and playing with it for ages and still can't see why.  Does anyone have a fix? - Please tell me it's not obvious. (FWIW - Chrome doesn't like my bottom).

Answer (score 1):

I think this line:

```
@page { counter-reset: page 1}
```

Means:

> “On each printed page, reset the `page` counter to 1.”

See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#propdef-counter-reset

Hence every page *would* have page number 1, as you’re resetting it to 1 on each page.

Does it work if you do `body { counter-reset: page 1}` instead? (Like in the example from the spec.)

Comment: Thanks Paul - but now every page has "Page Number 2".  Glad it's not turning out to be obvious.

Comment: Ah — right, because `#pageNumber` increments the counter each time, you want to reset it to `0` instead of `1`. I can’t reproduce the problem you’re describing (see http://jsfiddle.net/dXSaZ/), but is the problem only occurring when you print your page? It might help to see your full HTML.

Comment: I see what you've done with the fiddle is to have three divs - which is not what I have (the div.question-list-footer is repeated on every page - hence the bottom and position).  The rest of my html is just content (imagine a load of div's with text) that prints to more than one page.  Your post did lead me to thinking of moving the counter-increment to within the css for div.question-list-footer - but that had no effect either).- Thanks anyway.

Comment: Ah — have you just got the one `<div class="question-list-footer">`? Does it show up on every page when printed thanks to `position: fixed`?

Comment: Yep to the first question and yep to the second.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Okay: my last idea is to take your original code, and: 1. add `body { counter-reset: page 0}`, 2. replace `@page { counter-reset: page 1}` with `@page { counter-increment: page;}`, and 3. remove `#pageNumber { counter-increment: page; }`. Bear in mind that, as far as I know, [`@page` isn’t supported in Firefox](http://www.browsersupport.net/CSS/@page).

Comment: Yep, that's essentially where I'd gone from your suggestions.  But still no luck - sorry.  Probably going to suggest we leave out Page Number and set this in user agent (small number of users).

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

I think if you just remove this, the counter won't be reset so it will just increment like you want

```
@page { counter-reset: page 1}
```